# Applications of Objective-Z

Tags: z-notation

What are applications of Objective-Z?

I have read about Objective-Z, but I cannot imagine to what it would be applied.

This question may be too broad, but I do not think that there are too many answers.

Comment: I have noticed you're new here and many of your questions break the rules in some way. Take some time to read through the rules here to make your stay more pleasant. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-Z is an object-oriented extension to Z.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Z), you can get an overview of Objective-Z:

> Object-Z extends Z by the addition of language constructs resembling the object-oriented paradigm, most notably, classes. Other object-oriented notions such as polymorphism and inheritance are also supported.
>
> While not as popular as its base language Z, Object-Z has still received significant attention in the formal methods community, and research on aspects of the language are ongoing, including hybrid languages using Object-Z, tool support (e.g., through the Community Z Tools project) and refinement calculi.

For more information about the language and its uses, I would recommend visiting the [Objective-Z homepage](http://staff.itee.uq.edu.au/smith/objectz/objectz.html).

Its applications are similar to that of Z-notation - it is just an extension to a specification language.

If you *really* want to know about applications of Objective-Z, you can read [this book](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-1-4471-5354-2).

I hope this helps, and good luck with Z.

Answer (score 2):

[Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation) is a [specification language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_language), meaning it is used to describe a system.

A quote from the Wikipedia article about Specification Languages states:

> A specification language is a formal language in computer science used during systems analysis, requirements analysis and systems design to describe a system at a much higher level than a programming language, which is used to produce the executable code for a system.

The Z language is, according to [this source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation),

> a formal specification language used for describing and modelling computing systems. It is targeted at the clear specification of computer programs and computer-based systems in general.

So, that is the application of Z.

I see that your question is not about Z, but about Objective-Z, but I hope that this answer can still be useful.